# Recursively searching for files with specific extensions in a directory

Tags: python

For some reason this returns me an empty list, and I have no idea why.

```
import os, fnmatch

vidext = ['.avi', '.mkv', '.wmv', '.mp4', '.mpg', '.mpeg', '.mov', '.m4v']

def findExt(folder):
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folder):
        for extension in vidext:
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, extension):
                matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return matches

print(findExt("D:\TVRip"))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'd need to add a wildcard to each extension for `fnmatch.filter()` to match:

```
fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*' + extension)
```

but there is no need to use `fnmatch` here at all. Just use `str.endswith()`:

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(extensions):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

or expressed as a list comprehension:

```
return [os.path.join(r, fn)
        for r, ds, fs in os.walk(folder) 
        for fn in fs if fn.endswith(extensions)]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly ! Is this the fastest way to achieve this ?

Comment: Yes, I'd say this is the fastest way; the `endswith()` test is conducted entirely in C code.

Comment: Great! How would I exclude a specific director in the list comprehension approach? I tried `...for fn in fs if fn.endswith(extensions) and if '.dir_to_exclude' not in ds]`. But no effect.

Comment: @buhtz: delete the directories you want to ignore from the `dirnames` list so that they are not recursed into. `dirnames[:] = [dn for dn in dirnames if dn != '.dir_to_exclude']` updates the list in-place to remove an excluded name. The next iteration (which recurses into subdirectories) will then just skip that ignored subdir.