# Python recursively find files with specific extension

Tags: python, video

I am trying to find all movie files within a directory. Modified [some code found on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714013/recursively-searching-for-files-with-specific-extensions-in-a-directory), but it only finds 12 movie files, when in fact there are total 17 .mp4s and .movs w/in the directory... Ultimately, I'm trying to take screenshots of every video file at set intervals and have a quick way to generate a "contact sheet" when I get an HD of footage.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

folder_to_search = 'C:\\Users\\uname\\Desktop\\footage-directory'

extensions = ('.avi', '.mkv', '.wmv', '.mp4', '.mpg', '.mpeg', '.mov', '.m4v')


def findExt(folder):
    matches = []
    return [os.path.join(r, fn)
        for r, ds, fs in os.walk(folder) 
        for fn in fs if fn.endswith(extensions)]

print(len(findExt(folder_to_search)))
>>returns 12
```

[image]

Comment: works fine for me.it might be that you are not mentioning all the extension type in extensions ( set) which video file in footage-directory can have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> 'venom_trailer.Mp4'.endswith('mp4') # <-- file having .Mp4 extension is still a valid video file so it should have been counted. 
False

>>> 'venom_trailer.Mp4'.lower().endswith('mp4')
True

#------------
>>> file_name = 'venom_trailer.Mp4'
>>> last_occurance_of_period = file_name.rfind('.')
>>> file_extension = file_name[last_occurance_of_period:]
>>> file_extension
'.Mp4'
>>> file_extension.lower() == '.mp4'
True
#------------

# replace this line 
for fn in fs if fn.endswith(extensions) 
# with this
for fn in fs if fn.lower().endswith(extensions) 
# or with this
for fn in fs if fn[fn.rfind('.'):].lower() in extensions]
```